# An identity that comes from computing the Wiener index of a cyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory, summation, arithmetic

Can the below identity be proven in such a way that we can generalize it?

$(1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4) +( 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4)+ +( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 )+(1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2) + 1 = {4^3}$

This comes from computing the Wiener index for the cyclic graph with $8$ vertices.

Comment: what is going on?

Comment: Is it unclear for you? is this need modification?

Comment: It's very unclear. Can you provide the context?

Comment: Context is that this is related to finding distances between vertices. (Graph Theory)(Weiner Index of an even cycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can calculate the Weiner index of the 2n-gon as

$\dfrac 12\cdot 2n\left(2\cdot1+2\cdot2+\cdots+2\cdot (n-1)+n\right)$

Comment: thank you @ryagami. Is it possible to contact you again? I need this kind or relations

Comment: You're welcome. Do you understand why the formula is like it is? It's possible to contact me, but I'm not on the site so often and besides, you can ask all the questions here.

Comment: Yes almost this formula is clear for me.

Comment: Great. It can even be simplified to a closed form, but I'm guessing you can do that.

Comment: Yes yes I have done it's $n^3$. Now thinking for 2n+1-gon.

Comment: @user161618: by the same argument of the above proof, $$W(C_{2n+1})=\sum_{d=1}^n (2n+1)d = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I have understood the question correctly (hard to say), we are computing the Wiener index $W(G)$ of a cyclic graph $G=C_8$. The Wiener index for a graph over $n$ nodes is defined as:
$$ W = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} d_{ij}=\sum_{i<j}d_{ij} $$
where $d_{ij}$ is the graph distance between vertex $i$ and vertex $j$. For a cyclic graph over $n$ vertices, with the trivial labelling, we have $d_{ij}=\min\left(|i-j|,n-|i-j|\right)$, and the given sum computes $W$ by summing the contributes given by the vertices. Obviously, we can compute $W$ also by counting how many couples of vertices are within a given distance, running from $1$ to the diameter of $G$. In $C_{2n}$, the number of such couples is always the same, $2n$, unless the distance equals the diameter (in such a case there are only $n$ couples). This gives:

$$ W(C_{2n})=-n^2+\sum_{d=1}^{n}2nd = n^3.$$